# v-model full array inrow but not just value of row

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to display an array in a table. In one column, I use a checkbox that is either checked or unchecked, depending on the value of the v-model which should be the value of `array.selected` for each element.
However, the v-model contain *all* `array.selected` elements of the whole `array` but not just the one of the current row.

Does anybody know how to introduce some row check to only display the `array.selected` of the current row ?

**The HTML part:**

```
<b-table :items="rooms" :fields="roomsHeader">
    <template v-slot:cell(selected)="row" >
            <b-checkbox v-for="(item, index) in rooms" v-model="item.selected" :key="index"></b-checkbox>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

**The data:**

```
data () {
        return {
            rooms: [
                {
                    "room": "A",
                    "capacity": 80,
                    "selected": false,
                },
                {
                    "room": "B",
                    "capacity": 140,
                    "selected": true,
                },
                {
                    "room": "C",
                    "capacity": 100,
                    "selected": true,
                }
            ],
            roomsHeader: [
                {
                    key: 'room',
                    label: 'Raum'
                },
                {
                    key: 'capacity',
                    label: 'Kapazität'
                },
                {
                    key: 'selected',
                    label: 'Verfügbar'
                }
            ],
        }
    },
```

[Output screenshot (yellow the expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q5oD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content of slot `v-slot:cell(selected)="row"` is evaluated for each row of your table, so like this it will render **one checkbox for every row in your table in each row !**

You don't need `v-for` in that slot, just use `<b-checkbox v-model="row.item.selected" />`

Think about that *scoped slot* as a *callback* - every time `b-table` is rendering `selected` column in a current row, it will *call* your `cell(selected)` slot to get a content passing a current row as an argument...

[Docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering)